# Reference request: Discrete subgroup of $\mathrm{PO}(n,1)$ preserving proper subspace has infinite covolume

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, isometry-groups

I'm looking for a reference for the following claim:

$\newcommand{\PP}{\mathrm{PO}(n,1)}$
Let $\PP$ denote the group of isometries of $V = \mathbb{R}^{n,1}$ preserving the upper sheet of the hyperboloid (i.e. $\PP$ is the group of isometries of hyperbolic $n$-space), and $G$ a discrete subgroup of $\PP$.

**Claim.** If $G$ preserves a proper (linear) subspace of $V$, then $G$ is of infinite covolume in $\PP$.

The way I think a proof goes is:

- If $G$ preserves a subspace $U$, it preserves its orthogonal complement $U^\perp$ too.
- Either $U$ or $U^\perp$ either intersects the hyperboloid or contains an isotropic vector.
- Up to swapping $U$ and $U^\perp$, if $U$ intersects the hyperboloid, it preserves a proper subspace of hyperbolic space, and is therefore of infinite covolume.
- Similarly, if $U$ only contains an isotropic vector, it fixes an ideal point of hyperbolic space, and must also be of infinite volume.

I'm not 100% convinced by this argument, and I looked in Ratcliffe's and Vinberg's book for a better one and/or a reference, to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: Look up "Borel density theorem". Your specific argument sketch is ok, but this will give you a general reference.

Comment: Thanks! I did expect a more general phrasing than the one I use to hold (assuming the claim was true), but lacked the Lie group expertise to search intelligently.